# Importing Javascript module into Swift project. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, swift

I have a project that need to import JS Project into my Swift Project. I knew iOS have JavaScriptCore to interact with JS file. But with JS Project have so many files that link together. I wonder if there is a way to link code from JS Project to Swift Project. Or maybe some other approachs to use code JS for Swift Project.

Thank you very much and hope to see responses from everyone.

I tried successfully to work with 1 js file from my Swift proj.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your current working code (both the swift project as well as the single js file you're successfully loading) and what you changed in the JS file to import other files and the error message you got.